How to resolve OOM when .map concatenate the sharded parts?
When using the Dataset.map function:
dataset.map(myfunc, num_proc=16,  
    keep_in_memory=False, 
    cache_file_name='parts.arrow', 
    batch_size=16, writer_batch_size=16
)

Due to the size of my dataset, it results in:
/site-packages/datasets/table.py:1421:
  table = cls._concat_blocks(blocks, axis=0)
Killed

Looking carefully at the code in .map, I see that the shards are being created and the  .arrow files exists after the progress bar goes to 100%, then at it goes OOM at https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/2.21.0/src/datasets/arrow_dataset.py#L3276
            logger.info(f"Concatenating {num_proc} shards")
            result = _concatenate_map_style_datasets(transformed_shards)

Not sure if it's a bug that writing to individual arrow files work but the combination of the shard fails.
My machine has 80GB of RAM and each of the arrows files created after the transform function are around 100+GB.
Any way to resolve this and avoid the OOM in the _concat_blocks function in the Huggingface dataset object?

(This would be a comment if I had enough rep):
Try adding "batched=True" since it is False by default.
Although you of course set "batch_size=16" maybe the implementation of map doesn't turn batching on despite you setting that?
